# How to perform jquery code depening on which option is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7sARw/8/)

Please follow steps below in order to use the little application in the fiddle:

1. Click on "Open Grid" link and select a numbered button. A bunch of letter buttons will appear underneath. If you start selecting answer buttons then they turn green and in the "Number of answers" textbox above will start counting how many buttons you have turned on.
2. If you deselect all answer buttons however so that no answer buttons are turned on, then the text box above does not display `0` but instead display `1`.

This is because of the code below:

```
var container = $btn.closest(".optionAndAnswer");
// here the zero gets assigned
var answertxt = $(".answertxt", container);
var numberison = $(".answerBtnsOn", container).length;
if (answertxt.val() == 1 && numberison == 0) {
    numberison = 1;
}
answertxt.val(numberison);
```

I have include a comment in the jsfiddle in block capitals to state where this block of code is in the fiddle.

What I want to do is that if the option selected from the grid is either "True or False" or "Yes or No", then perform the code above where if no answer button is highlighted then the textbox value is 1. If it is any other option then if no answer buttons are selected then the textbox value should be 0.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, as you can see below, I'm checking if the selected type of input is true/false yes/no and by that I determine which code to run:

```
// ... 
var maxRowValue = $('.gridTxt', container).val();
if (maxRowValue === 'True or False' || maxRowValue === 'Yes or No') {
    if (answertxt.val() == 1 && numberison == 0) {
        numberison = 1;
    }
}
answertxt.val(numberison);
```